# How do you make __call() method for function calls?

Tags: php

I am trying to develop an application that intercepts functions. I know in class methods, you can have a __call() method for functions. I am wondering if such a thing exists for regular functions? I know there is a "function_exists" call, but then I'd have to do that every time I call a function. I'd like an automated approach.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What jonstjohn said... without discussing language features, what are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

There's no equivalent functionality.  Depending on your actual situation, you may be able to get some mileage out of __autoload(), which is the only magic function that's defined in global scope rather than for a class; it allows you to demand-define classes.

Answer (score 0):

Object Overloading is only available for classes. Also "function_exists" is very slow.

BTW there is also [is_callable](http://is.php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php)